# Site indexed on temporary domain before site went live

Tags: multiple-domains, development

I made a careless mistake with one of my sites. While developing it I put it on some temporary domain of mine and thought I would remove it after couple of days. That is why I did not included any robots.txt. Then due to some problems I completely forgot about it and did not do anything for 3 weeks. Now the site is completed and when I checked, google indexed all of its pages on my old domain.

Now I need to launch the site with the same content and I fear Google might think of the actual website as spam. What should I do to rectify it? I cannot wait for it to de-index.

I know it was stupid and will take care of it in future. But for such situations in future, what things I should keep in mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the future sign in to [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home) and claim both sites before indexing them. In there you can test/create your `robots.txt` files, sitemaps, `404`'s and a bunch of other tools.

Take a special look at the [Change address](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/change-address) tool. Matt Cutts [explains](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=83105) how to do it.

Basically, index the new site in Google. At the same time, redirect the old site to the new site with `301`'s. In time, the old site will be replaced with the new one. When the old site is completely removed from Google, you can undeploy it.

Comment: So here is what i wrote in my .htaccess file

redirect 301 /old_dir http://newdomain.com

put this at the root of my old domain and i hope this redirects all the files inside my folder properly. M i doing it right ??

One thing m still not sure about is that when should i remove the content from old site? I cannot keep it forever. So should i wait for it to get re-indexed properly or just delete it??

Comment: wait until it's completely un-indexed from serps. Then delete it without fear